# Данные загружаются с сервера, но не добавляются в ArrayList

Tags: android, retrofit

Столкнулся со следующей ситуацией: метод должен загружать данные с сервера и добавлять их в `ArrayList`. Вот код:

```
static List<Film> generateFilms(){
        Log.i(Tag, "In generate films");
        List <Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
        String BaseUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/";
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request original =  chain.request();
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", "auth-value");
            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        });
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        APIService apiService  = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        final Call<Film> filmsCall = apiService.getFilms();
        filmsCall.enqueue(new Callback<Film>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Film> call, @NonNull Response<Film> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Film film = response.body();
                    films.add(film);
                    Log.i(Tag, "Response: "+Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getTitle());
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(Tag, "Response code: "+response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Film> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: "+t);
            }
        });

        Log.i(Tag, "Size = "+films.size());
        return films;
    }
```

Но почему-то сначала возвращается массив и лишь потом в него добавляются данные. Как я понимаю, это из-за того, что данные получаются с сервера асинхронно. Как в таком случае исправить эту проблему?

Comment: 1) синхронный запрос (не применимо если метод вызван в UI-потоке). 2) метод ничего не возвращает, а событие, которое должно произойти после получения данных - вызывается из колбека запроса

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант для получения данных и обработки может быть пригодиться вам

```
private boolean sendHttpRequest(int city_id,String lang_id,String upd){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("city_id", String.valueOf(city_id))
            .addFormDataPart("lang_id", lang_id)
            .addFormDataPart("upd", upd)
            .build();

    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(http)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        String myResponse;
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            Log.d(TAG, e.toString()); // no need inside run()

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            myResponse = response.body().string();
            //Log.d(TAG, myResponse); // no need inside run()
            if(!getErrorFromRequest(myResponse)){

                getJsonHandler(myResponse);
            } // must be inside run()

        }
    });
    return  SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(getActivity()).getKey("key_some")!=null ? false : true;

}
```

отдельно сделал метод для обработки ошибок

```
private boolean getErrorFromRequest(String myResponse) {
  // тут ваши правила обработки
    return false;

}
```

Если у нас данные получены без каких либо проблем то обрабатываем

```
private void getJsonHandler(String myResponse) {
    getWhatYouNeed(myResponse,"key","key_to_save");
}

private void getWhatYouNeed(String response,String keygen, String key) {

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray object = obj.getJSONArray(keygen);

        SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(getActivity()).setKey(String.valueOf(object),key);
        Log.d("IsSet"+keygen, String.valueOf(object));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```